# How to run multiple scripts using command prompt

Tags: php, testing, phpunit, selenium-rc

I am able to make selenium scripts in the selenium IDE and also able to export it in PHPUnit. I also installed PHPUnit and the selenium-rc server (Which ran perfectly). Then I ran those scripts using the command: 'PHPUnit Testname.php' for which I got the output, But how can I Run Multiple Scripts at a time using the command..

Answer (score 0):

You may specify directory or directories to run tests. 
Or you can define directories in [configuration file](http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html) and run php unit like this:

```
phpunit --configuration path/to/config.xml
```

without any parameter it will run all tests.